# DirectShow IGraphBuilder Render error 0x80040218 (VFW_E_CANNOT_RENDER)

Tags: c++, directshow

I have the following problem:

On Windows 7, I try loading the contents of an *.mp3 file in memory and then play it using *IGraphBuilder*. This works well if I don't have certain applications running. If, however, I have BSPlayer open with an *.avi file or a game open, *IGraphBuilder* won't render the *.mp3 memory anymore. This does not happen if I have Winamp running, though.

I don't understand why this is happening, I'm suspecting that the input pins for DirectShow are all used? But when I run GraphEdt or similar applications together, they all work (play *.avi files or *.mp3 files in parallel), so there must be something I'm doing wrong in my program. Could you please help me out?

I have two classes: *CMemStream* and *CMemReader*, based on MS Windows 7.1 SDK's samples.

```
class CMemReader: public CAsyncReader
```

*CMemReader* doesn't do much, it just initializes the base class *CAsyncReader*.

```
class CMemStream: public CAsyncStream
```

*CMemStream* implements the *SetPointer, Read, Size, Alignment, Lock, Unlock* methods.

Here's the code (simplified):

```
IGraphBuilder *m_pGraphBuilder;
CMemStream *m_pMemStream;
CMemReader *m_pMemReader;

BYTE *m_pMemData = new BYTE[lSize];
// ... Fill in m_pMemData with the contents of an *.mp3 file
// lSize is the size of the file

m_pMemStream = new CMemStream(m_pMemData, lSize);

CMediaType mediaType;
mediaType.majortype = MEDIATYPE_Stream;
mediaType.subtype = MEDIASUBTYPE_MPEG1Audio;

HRESULT hResult;
m_pMemReader = new CMemReader(m_pMemStream, &mediaType, &hResult);

CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FilterGraph, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IGraphBuilder, (void**)&m_pGraphBuilder);

m_pGraphBuilder->AddFilter(m_pMemReader, NULL);
m_pMemReader->AddRef();
m_pGraphBuilder->Render(m_pMemReader->GetPin(0)); // THIS IS WHERE IT FAILS!
// The error is 0x80040218 (VFW_E_CANNOT_RENDER): No combination of filters could be found to render the stream.
```

I've also tried connecting the pins together, like so:

```
IBaseFilter *pFilter;
CoCreateInstance(CLSID_DSoundRender, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_IBaseFilter, (void**)&pFilter);

m_pGraphBuilder->AddFilter(pFilter, NULL);

IEnumPins *pEnumPins;
IPin *pPin;
pFilter->EnumPins(&pEnumPins);
pEnumPins->Next(1, &pPin, 0);

m_pGraphBuilder->Connect(m_pMemReader->GetPin(0), pPin); // THIS IS WHERE IT ALSO FAILS!
// The error is 0x80040217 (VFW_E_CANNOT_CONNECT): No combination of intermediate filters could be found to make the connection.
```

I've also tried different combinations for the type and subtype of *CMediaType*, but none work.

If you have any idea or suggestion, if you could spot a problem, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Instead of `Render`ing, try to `AddFilter` an instance of MPEG-I Stream Splitter and connect pins yourself. This is what `Render` would eventually do anyway, but you can have a more meaningful error code. Or, it might be fine and you rule out your own filter (the cause is something temporarily registered by this `BSPlayer` or exclusive use of audio output hardware etc.

Comment: Thanks, Roman, for the idea. What do you mean rule out my own filter? As you said, I tried creating a **CLSID_MPEG1Splitter** instance, then enumerating its pins. I get the **PINDIR_INPUT** pin, but I don't get any output pins. Not even if I explicitly use **FindPin(L"Audio", &pMPEGStreamSplitterPinOut)**. What might the problem be now?

Comment: I found a thread saying to re-register "quartz.dll". Now, when I try **Render**-ing the _mp3_ while _BSPlayer_ is running I get the 0x8004025C (VFW_E_UNSUPPORTED_AUDIO): "Cannot play back the audio stream: the audio format is not supported" error. I am still unable to get the output pins for **CLSID_MPEG1Splitter**. Note: If I **Render** the _mp3_ (_BSPlayer_ not running), then, if I enumerate the **CLSID_MPEG1Splitter** pins, I do get the output pins. If, however, the **Render** is not successful, I don't get the pins. Also, I don't get them before successfully calling **Render**...

Comment: I am not sure what BSPlayer is doing but if it affects your app the mentioned way then it is likely that the best thing would be to uninstall it. I don't understand the part with manual add of MPEG1Splitter: can you connect input? can you see output pin then? This is important and you don't need to Render before getting there.

Comment: Wow, thanks again, Roman! After connecting the source to the MPEG Stream Splitter In Pin then I could get the MPEG Splitter output pin. However, I can't connect this output pin to the input of CLSID_CMpegAudioCodec. I presume I'm not using the right codec? The error I get is VFW_E_CANNOT_CONNECT.

Comment: Managed to connect the pins to **LAVAudioDecoder**, both with BSPlayer stopped and running. BTW, BSPlayer is just the simplest example, the issue was also present when running certain games, like Prison Architect etc. Thanks a lot, Roman, I couldn't have done it without your help! :)